# c# CLR20r3 in Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, console

When i run my console application on my local system i didn't faced any error. But when i deployed my application to my **windows server 2008 r2** it throws an error as below,

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: testexcel.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 54294236
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.18444
  Problem Signature 06: 52717edc
  Problem Signature 07: 10eb
  Problem Signature 08: 6f
  Problem Signature 09: PSZQOADHX1U5ZAHBHOHGHLDGIY4QIXHX
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

In my code i'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll to generate the excel(.xls or .xlsx) and my servers doesn't have MS office. Is it possible to run my console application to generate the excel without installing MS office?

Can any one please help on this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the office interop I'm 99.9999999% sure you have to have office installed on each machine you are running it on.

You will have to use a 3rd party library to modify your documents.

[Similar Question with links in the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448197/how-to-use-microsoft-office-interop-excel-on-a-machine-without-installed-ms-offi)

Comment: For an alternate solution i have just create the .xls file to specified location using StreamWriter and load some text content to that .xls file. Excel is successfully created.When i attached that file to mail but, i'm unable to open that file via google docs

Comment: Is any other possibility to support the excel file in google docs which is created via StreamWriter?