# issue in text to excel file convert

Tags: excel, text, ms-office

i m creating excel file from text file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
here is my code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reading the text file - StreamReader include System.IO namespace
        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\pci218\Desktop\TextToExcelFormApplication\TextToExcelFormApplication\Text\pop3.txt");// Please give the file path  
        string sLine = "";
        ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();// Include System.Collections.Generic namespace
        while (sLine != null)
        {
            sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
            if (sLine != null)
                arrText.Add(sLine);
        }
        callExcel(arrText, true);
    }

    private void callExcel(ArrayList arrText, bool value)
    {
        try
        {
            // Change Your String here
            String textString = null;
            foreach (var item in arrText)
            {
                textString = textString + item + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            Clipboard.SetText(textString);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
            // for excel visibility
            //xlexcel.Visible = true;
            // Creating a new workbook
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            // Putting Sheet 1 as the sheet you want to put the data within
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            // creating the range
            Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
            CR.Select();
            xlWorkSheet.Paste(CR, false);
            if (value == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    // saving the file as .xls
                    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\U0153056\Desktop\receivedNew.xls");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File already exist");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    // saving the file as .xlsx
                    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\U0153056\Desktop\receivedNew.xlsx");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File already exist");
                }
            }
            xlexcel.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

but i m getting "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID"
error. i dont have microsoft office installed in my PC.is tht the problem? due to that m getting this error? anyone have idea .pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use **`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`** without having Microsoft Office Excel 2007 or later version installed.

> ... you must have Microsoft Office Excel 2007 and Microsoft Office
>   Word 2007, or later versions, installed on your computer.

Check **[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx)** link for more information.

Comment: is there any other way to convert text to excel without  using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel..

Comment: There are several ways but they are outdated, so not sure on that but you can check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11448322/1652222) and [**this**](http://forums.asp.net/post/4203658.aspx) links for example.