# How to fix the error for the interop when you dont have microsoft office installed

Tags: c#, service, com-interop, excel-interop

I have this code on my service:

```
Application xlsApp = new Application();
xlsApp.Visible = false;
Workbook wb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(dictionaryPath);
Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets;
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
var numberOfRows = ws.UsedRange.Columns["A"].Rows.Count;
var firstCol = ws.Range[dictionaryColumn + "1:" + dictionaryColumn + numberOfRows];
values = firstCol.Value as Array;
```

And when I run because I don't have Microsoft Office installed on my server I get this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>
> at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)

And I know that one of the solutions is to install the Microsoft Office but I am not allowed to do that so is there any other way to access the excel and not to install Microsoft Office. I use COM Interop and it is included in the project I also tried installing Open XML SDK 2.5 but for some reasons it didn't work. Can some one help me find a solution

Comment: You can't.  If you just need the data (no formatting) use oledb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel on a machine without installed MS Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448197/how-to-use-microsoft-office-interop-excel-on-a-machine-without-installed-ms-offi)