# Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, excel

Tried to compile a project after installing the required package, but I am still getting an error and I have no idea why since the error output is too generic.

Do you need to install Office? If so, which version? Because I checked on Stackoverflow and it seems you need to install it, but I am wondering if there's a way around this, because I don't have any license available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-install-office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2022

See How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies.

So it seems like I need to install it, but what I don't understand is why I need to do so since I should only require the NuGet package. Also, do you know which version of Office I need? I think I have a Office 2007 Ultimate license somewhere, but I am not sure if that would work.

Comment: If Office isn't installed, how do you plan on using the interop libraries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel on a machine without installed MS Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448197/how-to-use-microsoft-office-interop-excel-on-a-machine-without-installed-ms-offi)